# this is the error that appears in the code Property 'totalVuePackages' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I don't know how to do this, please help me. i am learning vue 3 js. I have to take the data with with verification.
(get link with jsonplaceholder)  But an error is written in the console:
Property 'totalVuePackages' does not exist on type '{ name: string; data(): { totalVuePackages: string; }; created(): void; }'.

```
<script lang='ts'>


import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'componentHome',

data(){
return{
  totalVuePackages:'',
}

},
created() {
  // GET request using axios with error handling
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(response => this.totalVuePackages = response.data.total)
    .catch(error => {
      
      this.errorMessage = error.message;
      console.error("There was an error!", error);
    });
}

}
```

```

```
I tried changing and renaming but it doesn't work.
I do not understand anything
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is a type error. You defined totalVuePackages as a string but the response coming from the api call is not a string value, that is why you are getting this error.
You can resolve this by replacing your data method like below code-

```
data(){
return{
  totalVuePackages:'' as any
 }
}
```

& your api call as:

```
axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
.then(response : any => this.totalVuePackages = response.data.total)
.catch(error => {
  
  this.errorMessage = error.message;
  console.error("There was an error!", error);
});
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Hi, I tried but it still throws an error. Says the same thing.  error :  Property 'totalVuePackages' does not exist on type ((((

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try this, hope it will resolve your issue!